# Target locally running .net core api service from a Xamarin Android emulator

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-core, android-emulator

I have a .net core service running locally.  The service is fired up through Visual Studio, and is running on localhost:45689.  I want to target this locally running service from an android application running on a Visual Studio Android emulator.  The emulator is running on the same machine as the service.

Using localhost:45689 as the host for requests from the application to the service doesn't work because localhost refers to the emulated device, and not my machine.  I tried using [ipaddress]:45689, and allowing requests inbound through the firewall for port 45689.  However, these requests just sit and time out.

If the service was being hosted through IIS, I could figure it out.  However, the hosting through IIS express seems to be causing me issues.  Is there any way to target my service in this manor from the emulated device?

Thanks,
Drew

Comment: by default IIS Express will not respond to requests from external IPs

Comment: https://programmingflow.com/2017/02/25/iis-express-on-external-ip.html

Comment: Thanks Jason.  The solution provided in the article didn't work for me, but did ultimately lead me to a solution that did work [iisexpress-proxy](https://github.com/icflorescu/iisexpress-proxy).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The final solution was to use [iisexpress-proxy](https://github.com/icflorescu/iisexpress-proxy).

However, I had to add a header value of host:localhost.  Pulled that little nugget from the comments on the link from Jason https://programmingflow.com/2017/02/25/iis-express-on-external-ip.html

-Drew